# load iframe after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

i have this code in my single.php page of wordpress for pop-up on click an   `<iframe>` on external site.

```
<a class="lbp-inline-link-1 cboxElement et_pb_pricing_table_button" href="#">Click_and_see_site</a>
<div style="display: none;">
<div id="lbp-inline-href-1" style="padding:10px; background: #fff;">
<iframe id="MyId" src="<?php echo $url_site; ?>" frameborder="0" style="height:97%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="97%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

I want load iframe only when pressed on "Click_and_see_site"

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(".lbp-inline-link-1").on('click',function (){

 $("#MyId").prop('src','<?php echo $url_site; ?>');
});
```

Also remove the SRC :

```
<iframe id="MyId" src="about:blank" ...
```